# Html.RenderAction not working with jQueryDataTable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

### Html Razor code

this code use in Edit view

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ActionNotes", "Prospects");}
```

### Ajax code

write ajax code in ActionNotes view.

```
var $dt =  @jQueryDataTable.Init("#tblActionNotes"
                                    , new DataTableOption(Model.List.Items)
                                    {
                                        AjaxSource = Url.Action("ActionNotes"),

                                        Dom = @IsOperator ? (((Model.UserRights & (int)CrmPermission.Add) == (int)CrmPermission.Add|| Model.TotalAccess) ? null :  "<\'row-fluid\'<\'span6\'F><\'span6\'>><\'row-fluid\'r>t<\'row-fluid\'<\'span3\'i><\'span3\'l><\'span6\'p>>" ) : (((Model.RoleRights & (int)CrmPermission.Add) == (int)CrmPermission.Add) ? null :  "<\'row-fluid\'<\'span6\'F><\'span6\'>><\'row-fluid\'r>t<\'row-fluid\'<\'span3\'i><\'span3\'l><\'span6\'p>>" ),  
                                        DeferLoading = Model.List.TotalItems,
                                        CreateUrl = Url.Action("ActionNoteNew","Prospects", new { id = Model.ProspectId }),
                                        Columns = new[] {
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="CreatedOn", Title="Date", Width="15%" },
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="CreatedByUserName", Title="Operator", Width="15%"  },
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="ToOperatorName", Title="Assign Operator", Width = "15%"},                                       
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="Note", Title="Note"  },
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="FollowUpDate", Title="Followup Date", Width="15%"  },
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="Type", Title="Type", Width="10%"  },
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="Status", Title="Status", Width="10%"  },
                                                        new DataTableColumnOption { Data="Id",Title = "Action", Width="80px", Render = "actionNoteActionRender", Sortable = false }
                                                     },
                                    })
        });
```

i use this code for call another controller and view for display two different view in single view, using this code second view is display properly and i can see data on edit view in (right click) page source but i can not display data on edit view page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110557/refreshing-html-renderaction-with-ajax-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve this issue using..

```
@{Layout = null;}
```

in Edit view before..

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ActionNotes", "Prospects");}
```